# How to create form inputs/elements in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

EDIT : My main question has now become 'How do I get the ServiceManager with the doctrine entity manager into the hands of my form, element, and input classes in some clean way?' Read on to see the full post.

I'm going to try and ask by example here so bear with me. Let me know where I'm going wrong/right or where I could improve

I'm trying to create a registration form. I could use ZfcUser module but I want to do this on my own. I'm using ZF2 with Doctrine2 as well so that leads me away from that module a bit.

My strategy was this,

1. Create a form class called registration form
2. Create separate 'element' classes for each element where each element will have an input specification
3. Since each element is a separate class from the form I can unit test each one separately.

All seemed fine until I wanted to add a validator to my username element that would check that the username is NOT is use yet.

Here is the code thus far

```
namepsace My\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form,
    Zend\Form\Element,
    Zend\InputFilter\Input,
    Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter,

/**
 * Class name : Registration
 */
class Registration
    extends Form
{

    const USERNAME     = 'username';
    const EMAIL        = 'email';
    const PASSWORD     = 'password';
    const PASS_CONFIRM = 'passwordConfirm';
    const GENDER       = 'gender';
    const CAPTCHA      = 'captcha';
    const CSRF         = 'csrf';
    const SUBMIT       = 'submit';

    private $captcha = 'dumb';

    public function prepareForm()
    {
        $this->setName( 'registration' );

        $this->setAttributes( array(
            'method' => 'post'
        ) );

        $this->add( array(
            'name'       => self::USERNAME,
            'type'       => '\My\Form\Element\UsernameElement',
            'attributes' => array(
                'label'     => 'Username',
                'autofocus' => 'autofocus'
            )
            )
        );

        $this->add( array(
            'name'       => self::SUBMIT,
            'type'       => '\Zend\Form\Element\Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Submit'
            )
        ) );

    }

}
```

I removed a lot that I think isn't necessary. Here is my username element below.

```
namespace My\Form\Registration;

use My\Validator\UsernameNotInUse;
use Zend\Form\Element\Text,
    Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface,
    Zend\Validator\StringLength,
    Zend\Validator\NotEmpty,
    Zend\I18n\Validator\Alnum;

/**
 *
 */
class UsernameElement
    extends Text
    implements InputProviderInterface
{

    private $minLength = 3;
    private $maxLength = 128;

    public function getInputSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'name'     => $this->getName(),
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array( 'name'       => 'StringTrim' )
            ),
            'validators' =>
            array(
                new NotEmpty(
                    array( 'mesages' =>
                        array(
                            NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'The username you provided is blank.'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                new AlNum( array(
                    'messages' => array( Alnum::STRING_EMPTY => 'The username can only contain letters and numbers.' )
                    )
                ),
                new StringLength(
                    array(
                        'min'      => $this->getMinLength(),
                        'max'      => $this->getMaxLength(),
                        'messages' =>
                        array(
                            StringLength::TOO_LONG  => 'The username is too long. It cannot be longer than ' . $this->getMaxLength() . ' characters.',
                            StringLength::TOO_SHORT => 'The username is too short. It cannot be shorter than ' . $this->getMinLength() . ' characters.',
                            StringLength::INVALID   => 'The username is not valid.. It has to be between ' . $this->getMinLength() . ' and ' . $this->getMaxLength() . ' characters long.',
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'name'    => '\My\Validator\UsernameNotInUse',
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            UsernameNotInUse::ERROR_USERNAME_IN_USE => 'The usarname %value% is already being used by another user.'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }    
}
```

Now here is my validator

```
namespace My\Validator;

use My\Entity\Helper\User as UserHelper,
    My\EntityRepository\User as UserRepository;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator,
    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface,
    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface,
    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

/**
 *
 */
class UsernameNotInUse
    extends AbstractValidator
    implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{

    const ERROR_USERNAME_IN_USE = 'usernameUsed';

    private $serviceManager;

    /**
     *
     * @var UserHelper
     */
    private $userHelper;
    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        UsernameNotInUse::ERROR_USERNAME_IN_USE => 'The username you specified is being used already.'
    );

    public function isValid( $value )
    {
        $inUse = $this->getUserHelper()->isUsernameInUse( $value );
        if( $inUse )
        {
            $this->error( UsernameNotInUse::ERROR_USERNAME_IN_USE, $value );
        }

        return !$inUse;
    }

    public function setUserHelper( UserHelper $mapper )
    {
        $this->userHelper = $mapper;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return My\EntityRepository\User
     */
    public function getUserHelper()
    {
        if( $this->userHelper == null )
        {
            $this->setUserHelper( $this->getServiceManager()->get( 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default' )->getObjectRepository( 'My\Entity\User') );
        }
        return $this->userHelper;
    }

    public function setServiceManager( ServiceManager $serviceManager )
    {
        echo get_class( $serviceManager );
        echo var_dump( $serviceManager );
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return ServiceManager
     */
    public function getServiceManager( )
    {
        return $this->serviceManager;
    }

}
```

Why did this seem like a good idea to me?

1. It seemed like a good testability/re-use choice to make since I could re-use the elements separately across my application if need be.
2. I could unit test each Input generated by each element to make sure it correctly accepts/rejects input.

This is the example of my unit test for the element

```
public function testFactoryCreation()
{
    $fac = new Factory();

    $element = $fac->createElement( array(
        'type' => '\My\Form\Registration\UsernameElement'
        ) );
    /* @var $element \My\Form\Registration\UsernameElement  */

    $this->assertInstanceOf( '\My\Form\Registration\UsernameElement',
                             $element );

    $input      = $fac->getInputFilterFactory()->createInput( $element->getInputSpecification() );
    $validators = $input->getValidatorChain()->getValidators();
    /* @var $validators \Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain */

    $expectedValidators = array(
        'Zend\Validator\StringLength',
        'Zend\Validator\NotEmpty',
        'Zend\I18n\Validator\Alnum',
        'My\Validator\UsernameNotInUse'
    );

    foreach( $validators as $validator )
    {
        $actualClass = get_class( $validator['instance'] );
        $this->assertContains( $actualClass, $expectedValidators );

        switch( $actualClass )
        {
            case 'My\Validator\UsernameNotInUse':
                $helper = $validator['instance']->getUserHelper();
                //HAVING A PROBLEM HERE
                $this->assertNotNull( $helper );
                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem I'm having is that the validator can't fetch the UserHelper properly, which is really a UserRepository from doctrine. The reason this is happening is because the validators only get access to the ValidatorPluginManager as a ServiceManager rather than having access to the application wide ServiceManager.

I get this error for the Validator portion, although if I call the same get method on the general service manager it works with no problems.

```
1) Test\My\Form\Registration\UsernameElementTest::testFactoryCreation
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default
```

The var_dump( $serviceManager ) in validator shows me it is of the class ValidatorPluginManager.

I tried putting a factory in the service_manager entry like so

```
'service_manager' => array(
                'factories' => array(
                    'My\Validator\UsernameNotInUse' => function( $sm )
                    {
                        $validator = new \My\Validator\UsernameNotInUse();
                        $em        = $serviceManager->get( 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default' );
                        /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
                        $validator->setUserHelper( $em->getRepository( '\My\Entity\User' ) );

                        return $validator;
                    }
                )
```

but that didn't work because it's not consulting the application level service manager.

So, overall, here are my questions :

1. Is this strategy of separating the form and elements a good one? Should I keep going this way? What are alternatives? ( I'm for breaking stuff up for the sake of testability ) I was going to test ONLY the form itself originally with a combination of ALL the inputs but it seemed like I'd be trying to do too much.
2. How do I resolve the issue I have above?
3. Should I be using the Form/Element/Input parts of Zend in some other way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Have you already checked the [docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html) about forms? I especially recommend using Annotations, as it's imo the fastest way to create forms.

Comment: @DanielM I have looked at the docs you mentioned but the question of 'how do i unit test each input separately?' remains. With the annotations method I would get a fully realized form right? So wouldn't I be forced to test using EVERY input combination?

Comment: Well, I don't test them. I don't think testing is required here because the element classes itself are tested, the validators are tested and so are the input filters. Of course, if you create a new Element class for a special purpose that doesn't fit the existing elements, you should create new test cases. Otherwise, its fine. And yes, forms created using annotations can be rendered completely without any work to do except `echo $this->formCollection($myForm);` inside the view if you don't need any customized rendering.

Comment: @DanielM I was going to follow the no testing route but I wanted to make sure my custom validator was being instantiated/used properly but it didn't work out so well because the validators don't get the generic service manager. This was another reason for testing too. This counts as more of an integration test I suppose.

Comment: If you create a custom validator class, you should of course also add test cases for it, yes. But I don't get your problem tbh.

Comment: @DanielM I've tested my custom validator class and it works fine. The problem is that the validator depends on having the doctrine entitiy manager and simply specifying the validator in the input specification WON'T magically pull in that dependency. How do I get the entity manager? That's what I should probably be asking.

Comment: I use static methods to inject the entityManager or reporitory as a dependency into validators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is my validator, using a static method to inject the entityManager and working with any doctine entity.

```
<?php

namespace Base\Validator;

use Traversable;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class EntityUnique extends AbstractValidator
{
    const EXISTS = 'exists';

    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::EXISTS => "A %entity% record already exists with %attribute% %value%",
    );

    protected $messageVariables = array(
        'entity' => '_entity',
        'attribute' => '_attribute',
    );


    protected $_entity;
    protected $_attribute;
    protected $_exclude;

    protected static $_entityManager;

    public static function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em) {

        self::$_entityManager = $em;
    }

    public function getEntityManager() {

        if (!self::$_entityManager) {

            throw new \Exception('No entitymanager present');
        }

        return self::$_entityManager;
    }

    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        if ($options instanceof Traversable) {
            $options = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($token);
        }

        if (is_array($options)) {

            if (array_key_exists('entity', $options)) {

                $this->_entity = $options['entity'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists('attribute', $options)) {

                $this->_attribute = $options['attribute'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists('exclude', $options)) {

                if (!is_array($options['exclude']) ||
                    !array_key_exists('attribute', $options['exclude']) ||
                    !array_key_exists('value', $options['exclude'])) {

                    throw new \Exception('exclude option must contain attribute and value keys');
                }

                $this->_exclude = $options['exclude'];
            }
        }

        parent::__construct(is_array($options) ? $options : null);
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);

        $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from($this->_entity, 'e')
            ->select('COUNT(e)')
            ->where('e.'. $this->_attribute . ' = :value')
            ->setParameter('value', $this->getValue());

        if ($this->_exclude) {

            $queryBuilder = $queryBuilder->andWhere('e.'. $this->_exclude['attribute'] . ' != :exclude')
                ->setParameter('exclude', $this->_exclude['value']);
        }

        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();        
        if ((integer)$query->getSingleScalarResult() !== 0) {

            $this->error(self::EXISTS);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

ie. i'm using it for theese form elements which are also tested and working fine:

```
<?php

namespace User\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element\Text;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface;

class Username extends Text implements InputProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct('username');
        $this->setLabel('Benutzername');
        $this->setAttribute('id', 'username');
    }

    public function getInputSpecification() {

        return array(
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringTrim'
                ),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                    'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            'isEmpty' => 'Bitte geben Sie einen Benutzernamen ein.',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

When creating a new user

```
<?php

namespace User\Form\Element;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface;
use User\Form\Element\Username;

class CreateUsername extends Username implements InputProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputSpecification() {

        $spec = parent::getInputSpecification();
        $spec['validators'][] = array(
            'name' => 'Base\Validator\EntityUnique',
            'options' => array(
                'message' => 'Der name %value% ist bereits vergeben.',
                'entity' => 'User\Entity\User',
                'attribute' => 'username',  
            ),    
        );

        return $spec;
    }
}
```

when editin an existing user

```
<?php

namespace User\Form\Element;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface;
use User\Form\Element\Username;

class EditUsername extends Username implements InputProviderInterface
{
    protected $_userId;

    public function __construct($userId) {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_userId = (integer)$userId;
    }

    public function getInputSpecification() {

        $spec = parent::getInputSpecification();
        $spec['validators'][] = array(
            'name' => 'Base\Validator\EntityUnique',
            'options' => array(
                'message' => 'Der name %value% ist bereits vergeben.',
                'entity' => 'User\Entity\User',
                'attribute' => 'username',
                'exclude' => array(
                    'attribute' => 'id',
                    'value' => $this->_userId,  
                ),
            ),    
        );

        return $spec;
    }
}
```

Comment: So when do you set the static entityManager? I think that this might be the way to go unless I plan on altering ZendF2 itself.

Comment: I'm going to wait to see if anyone posts any other attempts but I think that this is a good option. Thank you for your work.

Comment: in the application I'm setting it in the module.php of the module which contains the validator and in the tests I do it in the setup method of the testclass.