# ZF2 Db\RecordExists - Check additional columns

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a problem with ZF2 RecordExists method. I will explain my problematic case/scenario.

Table: users
Columns: id, emailaddress, websitename

```
Sample Records:
        1, user1@email.com, 1site.com
        2, user2@email.com, 1site.com
        3, user3@email.com, 2site.com
        4, user4@email.com, 2site.com
        5, user5@email.com, 1site.com
        6, user6@email.com, 3site.com
        7, user7@email.com, 4site.com
```

I am using the following snippet for already exist condition.

```
//Check that the email address exists in the database
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'field' => 'emailaddress'
    )
);

if ($validator->isValid($emailaddress)) {
    // email address appears to be valid
} else {
    // email address is invalid; print the reasons
    foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
    }
}
```

As per the above snippets, user1@email.com cannot register again. Because, that emailaddress is exist in table.
But, i would like to do register with 2site.com. Because, user1@email.com is in 1site.com.
So, user1@email.com cannot register with 1site.com again. But, user1@email.com can register with 2site.com.
How is it possible? Let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to do this.

First using [Excluding Record](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#excluding-records) methods 
Where you exclude the record of websitename field value.

> Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists and Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists
>   also provide a means to test the database, excluding a part of the
>   table, either by providing a where clause as a string, or an array
>   with the keys “field” and “value”.

```
$email     = 'user@example.com';
$clause    = $db->quoteInto('email = ?', $email);
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(
    array(
        'table'   => 'users',
        'field'   => 'username',
        'exclude' => $clause
    )
);

if ($validator->isValid($username)) {
    // username appears to be valid
} else {
    // username is invalid; print the reason
    $messages = $validator->getMessages();
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
    }
}
```

Second by writing your own custom validtor. 
You need to extend [AbstractDB](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/zendframework/zf2/namespace-Zend.Validator.Db.html) class and create your own class on directions of [RecordExists](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/zendframework/zf2/class-Zend.Validator.Db.RecordExists.html) Class. In your own cust class your can define your own query and pass it to isValid function.

I have created a Custom Validator oposite to Exclude, which is include. 
include is reserve word, Now sure if it will work. 
[check it here](https://gist.github.com/4635137)

More readings on this

[Guidlines 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342189/how-to-create-form-inputs-elements-in-zf2)

Please have look to existing validtor for creating your own custom validator[Custom validator guildline](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Validator/Db)

[Chain validator 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.validator-chains.html)